# SOLR group by different date ranges

Tags: search, solr

I have a lot of data in solr like this:

```
{
    id: some_id
    date: 2008-01-01T00:00:00Z
    price: 34.20
    currency: "CAD"
    weight: 39.9
    etc
}
```

I'd like to perform searches on it to find the unique set of ids, and group them by time. So sometimes I want to find the items that satisfy the search for each day, or week, or month.

The first way I tried to do this was set an `fq` (field query) to the date range I want, and set a `facet.field=id` to get the unique id for that range, but if I want to do this for each day I'd have to do 365(+0/+1) queries, which is quite a pain and very slow.

A solution to this was to use `facet.pivot=date,id` which would break this down into each day, and then for each day give the set of ids. This is perfect for the day case! However, how do we achieve the same thing for weekly? Or monthly?

What I want is the first `facet.pivot`, which is date, to be a range of values. So instead of getting this:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    ...
  },
  "facet_counts":{
    ...
    "facet_pivot":{
      "date,id":[{
          "field":"date",
          "value":"2008-01-01T00:00:00Z",
          "count":923,
          "pivot":[{
              "field":"id",
              "value":18,
              "count":1},
            {
              "field":"id",
              "value":66,
              "count":1},
            {
              "field":"id",
              "value":70,
              "count":1},
        ]
      }
      ...]
    }
}
```

We get something like this:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    ...
  },
  "facet_counts":{
    ...
    "facet_pivot":{
      "date,id":[{
          "field":"date",
          "value":"2008-01-01T00:00:00Z TO 2008-01-31T00:00:00Z",
          "count":923,
          "pivot":[...similar to above]
      }
      ...]
    }
}
```

In other words, instead of it grouping based on the value of `date`, it groups based on a range/interval/etc. I've toyed around with SOLRs interval,range, etc but can't seem to get something that works.

Answer (score 1):

Please try like below to get the monthly range with the gap of week.

`facet.range={!tag=rdt}date&facet.range.start=NOW/DAY&facet.range.gap=+7DAY&facet.range.end=NOW/DAY +30DAY&facet=true&facet.pivot={!range=rdt}date,id`

I hope this helps!